# trie reg exp parse step over char and continue

Tags: recursion, string-matching, trie

Setup: 1) a string trie database formed from linked nodes and a vector array linking to the next node terminating in a leaf, 2) a recursive regular expression function that if A) char '*' continues down all paths until string length limit is reached, then continues down remaining string paths if valid, and B) char '?' continues down all paths for 1 char and then continues down remaining string paths if valid. 3) after reg expression the candidate strings are measured for edit distance against the 'try' string.

Problem: the reg expression works fine for adding chars or swapping ? for a char but if the remaining string has an error then there is not a valid path to a terminating leaf; making the matching function redundant. I tried adding a 'step-over' ? char if the end of the node vector was reached and then followed every path of that node - allowing this step-over only once; resulted in  a memory exception; I cannot find logically why it is accessing the vector out of range - bactracking?

Questions: 1) how can the regular expression step over an invalid char and continue with the path? 2) why is swapping the 'sticking' char for '?' resulting in an overflow?

Function:

```
void Ontology::matchRegExpHelper(nodeT *w, string inWild, Set<string> &matchSet, string out, int level, int pos, int stepover)
{   
    if (inWild=="") {
        matchSet.add(out);
    } else {
        if (w->alpha.size() == pos) {
            int testLength = out.length() + inWild.length(); 
            if (stepover == 0 && matchSet.size() == 0 && out.length() > 8 && testLength == tokenLength) {//candidate generator
                inWild[0] = '?';
                matchRegExpHelper(w, inWild,  matchSet, out, level, 0, stepover+1);
            } else 
                return; //giveup on this path
        }
        if (inWild[0] == '?' || (inWild[0] == '*' && (out.length() + inWild.length() ) == level ) ) { //wild
            matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, inWild.substr(1), matchSet, out+w->alpha[pos].letter, level, 0, stepover);//follow path -> if ontology is full, treat '*' like a '?'
        } else if (inWild[0] == '*')
            matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, '*'+inWild.substr(1), matchSet, out+w->alpha[pos].letter, level, 0, stepover); //keep adding chars
        if (inWild[0] == w->alpha[pos].letter) //follow self
            matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, inWild.substr(1), matchSet, out+w->alpha[pos].letter, level, 0, stepover); //follow char 
        matchRegExpHelper(w, inWild, matchSet, out, level, pos+1, stepover);//check next path
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
+str    "Attempt to access index 1 in a vector of size 1." std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
+err    {msg="Attempt to access index 1 in a vector of size 1." } ErrorException
```

Note: this function works fine for hundreds of test strings with '*' wilds if the extra stepover gate is not used

Semi-Solved: I place a `pos < w->alpha.size()` condition on each path that calls `w->alpha[pos]...` - this prevented the backtrack calls from attempting to access the vector with an out of bounds index value. Still have other issues to work out - it loops infinitely adding the ? and backtracking to remove it, then repeat. But, moving forward now.

Revised question: why during backtracking is the position index accumulating and/or not deincrementing - so at somepoint it calls  `w->alpha[pos]...` with an invalid position that is either remaining from the next node or somehow incremented `pos+1` when passing upward?

Comment: after an hour of tracing step tracks, it looks like the path terminates and the recursion backtracks up three nodes to the '?' and increments to the next char in the vector at the node stepped over. At some point the position is 1 and the vector is size 1, and so an out of bounds vector cell is referenced. Help.

Comment: found a contributing problem, for the test case there was only one linked node at the stepover. So when that path did not work, it backtracked back to the stepover and tried the next path - that did not exist. But, why did it try another path, since all paths were tried (w->alpha.size() == pos)` should have terminated the function. The backtracking did something before reaching that conditional test.

Comment: I think it makes sense to combine a reg exp function into the distance match function and handle the invalid paths there. If I only want reg exp for valid paths then I use reg exp function or if invalid paths are considered then I use the match function. The question about why the backtracking caused an attempt to access an invalid vector cell remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: combine the regular expression wilds function as loops in the matching function